# HTML How to open the URL in Firefox browser to render HTML 5 content

Tags: html, firefox, browser

I have a requirement to open the URL to HTMLpage in Firefox. The reason being Google Chrome Frame is not allowed to be installed and default browser is IE6, hence trying to open the HTML 5 content in Firefox. The content must be first loaded using IE6 as there are some component which only IE6 can support.

is it possible to open the specific urls in firefox when user clicks the link?

If someone could help with above will be much appreciated.

Tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
<a href="file:///c:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe http://channel9.msdn.com/">Visit MSDN Channel 9</a>
```

Comment: what are you trying to develop ? a website ? (Note : the -1 is not from me)

Comment: If it "must be loaded using IE6" then you're in a bind and can't use FF. Perhaps you can convince "the company" to allow/update to IE9?

Comment: trying to develop a custom HTML files, it's a not a website.

Comment: Wait, when you say custom HTML files, do you mean a single page, or do you mean you are trying to scrape the data to use elsewhere?

Comment: Hi Anthony it's a multiple HTML pages. The main html will have link to other html pages.

Comment: This is absolutely impossible, and for good reason. You would not want any website you visit, or any link you click, to be able to launch random executables on your computer... what if it launched `RMDIR` on your root directory. Just use a single browser, dude.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want/need the user to visit a site via IE6 to load some old ActiveX stuff, and then from there open a new window with HTML5 content but open it in Firefox?

The closest I can come to imagine how to do this (and it's a longshot), would be to assign the new window an href with a non-http protocol, maybe something like "html5:" or even "firefox:". and perhaps IE6 will ask what program to use for that protocol.  but even in that case, Firefox won't know what to do with that protocol either. It may just guess from the mime-type.

But I don't think there is a kosher way to force one browser to open a window in another browser (that I know of).

Another thing to consider:  I used to have, amongst may other one-off staff sites, one site that was IE only and would boot you out otherwise.  It turns out it was just the server checking if it was IE because at that time they were worried Netscape wouldn't handle the CSS and javascript correctly.

To test if it's truly IE dependent content (and not just IE enforced), try using a [UA switcher plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) for Firefox and spoof your UA string to say it's IE6. If the page looks great in Firefox, then it's not truly an IE only page, just some old browser-sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

Using a browser that supports some of the newer functionality within HTML5 is really the only way to use that functionality. So, I see why you are trying to open that link within a more modern browser such as FF. I do not think that you will be able to open a particular link, launching another browser.

However, if you are just trying to display a webpage that degrades gracefully in IE6, then you can start using HTML5 and there's no need to open said link in FF. Paul Irish says so. Checkout [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

If you are trying to use a certain functionality only available in HTML5 on your page/link, I would suggest checking to see if you can get the same effect/functionality in JavaScript. Things like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) or [polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) could help.